# Why can't call freeRTOS API within a critical section?

Tags: c, operating-system, arm, stm32, freertos

Now I'm learn freeRTOS api " taskENTER_CRITICAL()" in FreeRTOS V9.0.0 reference manual.
    I find such description for this API: 
   "FreeRTOS API functions must not be called from within a critical section"
   Why? why we can't call freertos api whthin a critical section? like below show:

```
taskENTER_CRITICAL();
do_something..
xQueueReceive();  // ?? why can't call this api within this critical setction ??
taskEXIT_CRITICAL();
```

Hope response from anyone, Thanks!

BR//David Wang

Comment: Well, I don't know any details about freeRTOS but it sounds like when they say a critical section, they really mean a CRITICAL section. Like interrupt handlers keep it short. LIke 200 CPU instructions short.

Comment: Thanks! But if I call some FreeRTOS system call within CRITICAL section, what will happen? system crash or system hang or ... ?

Comment: @DavidWang Try it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Interrups are avoided in code written in critical section. **xQueueReceive()** also working by interrups that is main reason.